# Не добавляються данные в базу

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться почему не добавляются данные в базу!
Вот база:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Код php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$auth = $_POST['auth'];
$ganr = $_POST['ganr'];
$discp = $_POST['discp'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('catalog',$link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO books(name,author,genre,discription,price) VALUE ('$name','$auth','$ganr','$discp','$price')");
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="admin.php">
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Название</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Автор</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="auth" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Жанр</td>
<td valing="top"><input name="ganr" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Описание </td>
<td valing="top"><textarea name="discp" cols="22"
rows="10" > </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Цена </td>
<td valing="top"><input name="price" type="text" value="" size="30"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Очистить" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто писать надо аккуратно, и всё. Единственная ошибка тут — в списке полей вы написали `discription` вместо `description`.

Еще тут готовый SQL-injection, кстати.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Стоило упомянуть как этого избежать. И к автору вопроса - стоит оптимизировать код, ведь будут вылезать ошибки при посте например со стороннего js с пустыми данными. Да вроде даже с пустой формой.

Comment: И еще в запросе - VALUE, когда надо VALUES.

Comment: Добрый и покладистый MySQL сожрет и VALUE. Но Лёлик, это ж не эстетично :)